# Custom database-driven CDI Context

Tags: java, cdi

I'd like to extend usage of CDI in the app I develop. What I need is something like application context/scope but I need to handle multiple instances of beans based on how many records are in the database/configuration.

To be more specific, in our database, there's a table called PODs and for each record in this table, I need a separate group of beans (services, repositories, etc. - a whole object graph). There's no need for dynamic behaviour - it's OK to restart application when a record is created/deleted in this PODs table. But ideally items defined within this PodContext for a specific POD should be able to inject beans within the context of the same PodContext.

The obvious problem here is how to specify for which POD a bean instance should be created/injected.

That leads me to a question if a custom CDI context is actually suited for such a use case but without losing all the CDI goodies and building all the object graphs manually, I don't see a good way out :(

Update: My colleague suggested a solution for Spring Framework - we could have a parent context with all the shared application-wide beans, and also one child context for each POD, which would define beans for that specific POD. It's possible because Spring allows such context hierarchies. Is there anything similar in CDI?